# alamofire is not preparing correct url

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlconnection

I am using alamofire for calling webservice.

```
request(url, method: webMethod, parameters: webParams, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            print("responseresponse===\(response.request)")
```

I am getting below log for the same.

```
responseresponse===http://www.mywebsite.com/api/searchFlight?
    adults=3&charter=true&directFlight=true&
    flexibleDays=0&flightClass=PREMIUM_ECONOMY&
    offerLimit=10&refundableOnly=false&
    routes%5B%5D=KWI-BOM%2C2018-08-09&routes%5B%5D=BOM-KWI%2C2018-08-25
```

Params I am passing as below & they are of type [String: Any]

```
[
    "adults": 3, 
    "directFlight": "true", 
    "flightClass": "PREMIUM_ECONOMY", 
    "refundableOnly": "false", 
    "offerLimit": 10, 
    "flexibleDays": "0", 
    "charter": "true", 
    "routes": ["KWI-BOM,2018-08-09", "BOM-KWI,2018-08-25"]
]
```

This return me status code as 400 which means Invalid request.

I don't understand why routes are giving wrong output? Routes are coming as below

```
routes%5B%5D=KWI-BOM%2C2018-08-09&routes%5B%5D=BOM-KWI%2C2018-08-25
      ^^^^^^                            ^^^^^^
```

I was expecting routes to be as below.

```
routes=KWI-BOM%2C2018-08-09&routes=BOM-KWI%2C2018-08-25
```

I idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is what I did

### Swift3

***Remove square brackets for GET request***

```
struct CustomGetEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var request = try URLEncoding().encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
        request.url = URL(string: request.url!.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "%5B%5D=", with: "="))
        return request
    }
}

...

Alamofire.request("http://example.com", method: .get, parameters: ["foo": ["bar1", "bar2"]], encoding: CustomGetEncoding())
```

***Remove square brackets for POST request***

```
struct CustomPostEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var request = try URLEncoding().encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
        let httpBody = NSString(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
        request.httpBody = httpBody.replacingOccurrences(of: "%5B%5D=", with: "=").data(using: .utf8)
        return request
    }
}

...

Alamofire.request("http://example.com", method: .post, parameters: ["foo": ["bar1", "bar2"]], encoding: CustomPostEncoding())
```

---

### Swift2

***Remove square brackets for GET request***

```
let parameterEncoding = ParameterEncoding.Custom { requestConvertible, parameters in
    let (mutableRequest, error) = ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(requestConvertible, parameters: parameters)
    mutableRequest.URL = NSURL(string: mutableRequest.URLString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%5B%5D=", withString: "="))
    return (mutableRequest, error)
}

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://example.com", parameters: ["foo": ["bar1", "bar2"]], encoding: parameterEncoding)
```

***Remove square brackets for POST request***

```
let parameterEncoding = ParameterEncoding.Custom { requestConvertible, parameters in
    let (mutableRequest, error) = ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(requestConvertible, parameters: parameters)
    let httpBody = NSString(data: mutableRequest.HTTPBody!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    mutableRequest.HTTPBody = httpBody.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%5B%5D=", withString: "=").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return (mutableRequest, error)
}

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://example.com", parameters: ["foo": ["bar1", "bar2"]], encoding: parameterEncoding)
```

### [Reference](https://256days.com/post/how-to-remove-square-brackets-with-alamofire/)

Answer (score 0):

`%5B%5D` is UrlQueryAllowed encoded `[]`. That's Alamofire striking again - it sees that `routes` param is a dictionary so it passes `routes[]=foo&routes[]=bar` instead of `routes=foo&routes=bar` and your backend complains about wrong parameter (`routes` is mandatory?). Not quite sure why Alamofire does this and if HTTP needs an array parameters to have `[]` at the end of their key - never had to pass an array as a query param. I'd simply try encoding the `routes` by hand and passing `routes: <String>` with some delimiter.

Or change my backend to expect `routes[]` instead of `routes`. That seems the easier fix.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that the webmethod is equals to .post and trying to change enconding: JSONEncoding.default, in that case the request do not send the data through the url but from the body data. That is because complex data can not be sent through the url. Also try to verify that your end-point recieve an object with the same property names and that the types match. I've performed several post request with Alamofire and they worked as expected.